# magento:how to use Mastercard 3D Secure

Tags: php, magento

Is there any resource on how to implement Mastercard 3d secure with magento,

i read the mastercard secure code page

```
http://www.mastercard.com/uk/merchant/en/security/what_can_do/SecureCode/
```

but i'm n't sure what steps should i do

i'm not asking for the code, i just need some resources.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your store's admin go to *System > Configuration > Payment Services* and you should see a section for controlling 3D Secure. If you have an older version of Magento it might not have this feature yet.